# Transpose column into rows without summing

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table:

```
    id     name     year     month     value     code
    1      George   1991       1       675       1234
    2      George   1991       2       675       1234
    3      George   1991       2       675       1234
    5      George   1991       3       675       1234
    ...    ...      ...       ...      ...       ...
```

but I have to show it like this, so I can have months in a row with one id:

```
    id     year     name     code     jan     feb     mar     apr   ...  dec
    1      1991     George   1234     675     675     675      0          0
    2      1991     George   1234      0      675      0       0          0
    ...    ...      ...      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   ...  ...
```

the thing is: There can be more than 1 value in the same month, and I couldn't create that structure without summing the values (in this example, february), and I don't want that. Is there any way to do this using a pivot or something??

Comment: what flavour of database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple values for each month that you want to keep unique, then you should consider applying a `row_number()` prior to using the `PIVOT`:

```
select name, year, code,
  coalesce([1], 0) as jan,
  coalesce([2], 0) as feb,
  coalesce([3], 0) as mar
from
(
  select name, year, month, value, code,
    row_number() over(partition by name, year, month
                      order by year, month) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for month in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b547/5)

The result is:

```
|   NAME | YEAR | CODE | JAN | FEB | MAR |
------------------------------------------
| George | 1991 | 1234 | 675 | 675 | 675 |
| George | 1991 | 1234 |   0 | 675 |   0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

What would be wrong on using PIVOT for it?

With this kind of query you get the result you're excepting, when there is uniqueness among ID, NAME, CODE, YEAR and MONTH.

```
select id, name, code, year,
        [1] as JAN,
        [2] as FEB,
        ...
        [11] as NOV,
        [12] as DEC
from (
        select id, name, code, year, month, value
        from <table>
    )
pivot (
    max (value) for month in ([1],[2], ... [11],[12])
)
```